# Excel Application.Match Run-time error '13'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use application.match to allow me to find the position of a matching date in a table column, I've not been able to get it to work, between 1004 errors and mismatch errors and no google result seems to help.

Below is the code and it runs fine until I try to use or display the result from the match

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
Me.ComboBox1.Value = Format(Me.ComboBox1.Value, "dd/mm/yy")
TheDate = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click()
Dim TheDate As Variant
TheDate = ComboBox1.Value
Pos = Application.Match(TheDate, Sheet1.Range("B5:B30"), 0)
Label1.Caption = Pos
End Sub
```

I'm new to this so I wouldn't be surprised if its something obvious

Thanks

Comment: When it is only the display, have you tried to display your result in other ways? Like Depug.print or show the result in a wrtieable textbox?

Comment: Where, and how, did you define Pos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel stores dates as numbers... Try this

```
Pos = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(TheDate)), Sheet1.Range("B5:B30"), 0)
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked :) Working with dates is very tricky in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
Dim theDate As Date

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim pos As Variant

pos = Application.match(CLng(theDate), Sheet1.Range("B5:B30"), 0)
If Not IsError(pos) Then
    Label1.Caption = pos
Else
    MsgBox "No Such Date", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
theDate = Date
Me.ComboBox1.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy")
End Sub
```